# How to log to console or file for different profiles with jar execution?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logging, logstash

I am using Spring Boot `2.3.1` with Lombok logging - [@Slf4j](https://projectlombok.org/features/log) annotation.

I have two profiles: `dev` and `default`. With appropriate `application.yml` & `application-dev.yml` config files.

Finally, the project is built with maven and the *final jar* file is launched in AWS *EC-2 Windows instance*.

Currently, there aren't any log files configured, so jar execution looks like:

> java -jar -DmyProp=myVal ... myJar.jar > log_file.log &

It starts program execution at the background and all output is redirected to log file.

It isn't so good and configurable as it should be.

So, for now, want to add different log behaviours:

- dev profile -> log to console only
- default -> log to file with Rolling file appender

Created following `logback-spring.xml` and put it to resources folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs"/>
    <!-- use Spring default values -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/my_log.log</file>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>
                ${LOGS}/archived/my_log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <springProfile name="dev">
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="com.siemens" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </logger>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="!dev">
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="com.demo" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

When I run the jar file with previously mentioned Maven command I don't have any logging to file. Everything is logged to console despite the fact that I launched it at background mode.

I tried to use additional configuration for `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    name: my_log.log
    path: C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\my-service\logs
```

However, the result is the same.

***How to create different log strategies for different profiles and use it with jar launching?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After play around for a while found a solution.

Update `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner_mode: OFF
```

Eliminate configs like:

```
logging:
  level:
    name: my_log.log
    path: C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\my-service\logs
```

Logback config file is correct and should be the same.

And now when you could launch your app:

> java -jar -DmyProp=myVal ... myJar.jar &

That's it. It will launch and all output will be logged to the log file only.

If you will enable banner again -> it will be printed at the console output and hang up with it.
So it must be disabled.